# Cucumber Testing, Counting Page Elements

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I am using cucumber-jvm and writing BDD tests.

I would like to write the step definition for "Then I should see three posts on a page" (The class name is Post)

So my best guess is:

```
expect(page).to have_css("tbody tr.#{Post}", count: 3)
```

But that does not work

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
element = all("tbody tr.#{Post}")
element.count
```

That should do the trick...